# Holomorphic function $f$ on the unit disc such that $|f(z)|\leq 1.$

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $f$ be a holomorphic function on $D=\{z\in\mathbb{C}:|z|\leq 1\}$ such that $|f(z)|\leq 1.$

$$g(z)=\begin{cases} \dfrac{f(z)}{z} &\text{ if } z\neq 0\\[8pt] f'(0) &\text{ if } z=0.\end{cases}$$

Which of the following statements are true

$1.$ $g$ is holomorphic on $D.$

$2.$ $|g(z)|\leq 1$ for all $z\in D.$

$3.$ $|f'(z)|\leq 1$ for all $z\in D.$

$4.$ $|f'(0)|\leq 1.$

By Riemann removablity theorem it is clear that $g$ is holomorphic on $D.$ I don't know how to handle other options. Please help me. Thanks a lot.

Comment: By holomorphic on $D$ you mean $f$ is holomorphic on a domain containing $D$ (because usually holomorphicity is defined for domains only)?

Comment: Yes it will be so...

Comment: Are you assuming $f$ fixes origin?

Comment: You did not say f(0)=0, but it must be for g to be holomorphic on D

Comment: [Schwarz lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwarz_lemma)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $f(0)\ne 0$ then $g$ is not holomorphic on $D.$ The case $f(z)=1$ ($\;$for all $z\in D\;$) refutes (1) and (2). Number (3) is refuted by $f(z)=z^2,$ as $|f'(3/4)|=3/2.\;$ Number (4) is true, as $$|f'(0)|=\left|\frac {1}{2\pi i}\int_{|z|=1}\frac {f(z)}{z^2} dz \right|\leq \frac {1}{2\pi}\int_{|z|=1}\frac {|f(z)|}{|z|^2} |dz| \leq \frac {1}{2\pi}\int_{|z|=1}|dz|=1.$$

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Maximum modulus principle for your function on $\mathbb{D}$ .  The answer is $g$ is holomorphic and $|f'(0)|\le 1$

Comment: I think Schwartz's lemma holds for open unit disc.

Comment: But this is not the solution of the given problem..

Comment: I said maximum modulus principle.